# Create a report in SCCM 2007 the shows server without a piece of software

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

Does anyone have a query that shows a list of servers WITHOUT a selected piece of software?  i.e. SCOM agent, anti-virus, backup agent.

Answer (score 4):

This basic SQL will show all computers that do not have a piece of software installed that matches `forefront`.

```
SELECT ResourceID, Name0, SMS_Unique_Identifier0
FROM v_R_System
WHERE ResourceID NOT IN
(
  SELECT ResourceID
  FROM v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE
  WHERE ProductName0 LIKE '%forefront%'
)
```

You can replace `forefront` with the name of the software you are interested in.

The idea is to craft a query that will give you all computers that **do** have the software installed, then use `NOT IN` to turn it around and get computers that **don't** have the software installed.

Here it is again, but in WQL for a Query:

```
SELECT SMS_R_System.Name
FROM SMS_R_System
WHERE SMS_R_System.ResourceId NOT IN
(
  SELECT SMS_G_System_Installed_Software.ResourceId
  FROM SMS_G_System_Installed_Software
  WHERE SMS_G_System_Installed_Software.ProductName LIKE "%forefront%"
)
```

Comment: The query seemed to work for the most part, however in the collection there are a lot of servers that do have Sophos (Our AV).  When running the Products on a specific computer report, under product name, there are entries LIKE "%Sophos%".  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found using ARP more accurate:

```
    select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client 
    from SMS_R_System 
    where SMS_R_System.ResourceId not in 
    (
select SMS_R_System.ResourceId from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS on SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName LIKE "%<Application Name>%"
    ) 
    and SMS_R_System.Client = 1 
    and SMS_R_SYSTEM.OperatingSystemNameAndVersion like 'Microsoft Windows NT%Server%'
```